# Magento 2: Adding Arbitrary HTML to the <head> of Every Page?

Tags: php, layout, magento2

In Magento 2, is it possible to add an arbitrary bit of HTML to every frontend/cart page's `<head/>`?

I know I can add a block to the content/`<body>` area with code something like this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block type="Pulsestorm\Test\Block\Head" name="pulsestorm.head" as="pulsestorm.head" template="pulsestorm/head.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

However, it's not clear if there's a similar block for adding content to the `<head/>` element of a page.    I've looked through the dev docs site and the source code, and there's lots of references to **new** tags you can use with a `<head/>` tag

```
<head>
    <css.../>
    <js.../>
</head>
```

but I can't find any reference of a way to add arbitrary html/text to the `<head/>` section of a page in Magento 2.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

not 100% sure about this, but I think you can add code to the head using this:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Pulsestorm\Test\Block\Head" name="pulsestorm.head" as="pulsestorm.head" template="pulsestorm/head.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I know, it sounds strange to add code in the `<body>`but render it in the `<head>` but here is why I think so:

The "skeleton" of the page is determined by this template: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml
This template echos `$headAdditional` (and other variables)
These variables are initialized in [\Magento\Framework\View\Result::render()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page.php#L234)  and the var `$headAdditional` looks like this:

```
'headAdditional' => $addBlock ? $addBlock->toHtml() : null,
```

where `$addBlock` is

```
$addBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head.additional');
```

Then I search for references to `head.additional` and found this in [`app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_opengraph.xml`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_opengraph.xml)

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="opengraph.general" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/general.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="opengraph.currency" as="meta.currency" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/currency.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I didn't test the actual code (I'm getting lazy) but it's the only lead I have.

Comment: In a year or two you'll be lazy enough to just ask a question on Stack Exchange when you have one :)  The above worked perfectly (eye rolls and head shakes not withstanding)

Comment: If representative: this is the butterfly flap preceding the tsunami of how much I'm going to dislike the way M2 names things.

Comment: @BrendanFalkowski A tsunami of flapping butterflies each preceding a tsunami of drowning flapping butterflies each preceding a tsunami ;(