# equivalent class for Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head

Tags: magento2, head

what is the equivalent class for `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` in magento2?
I'm finding `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header`.
But there is no class related to `Head.php`

Update:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
class Gigya_Social_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {

  protected function _construct() {
    if (Mage::helper('Gigya_Social')->isPluginEnabled('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf')) { // check if gigiya plugin enabled
      $this->setTemplate('page/html/head.phtml'); // set output template

      $uriPrefix = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://cdns' : 'http://cdn'; // check if domain is secured and set gigya domain accordingly
      $gigyaApiKey = trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf/apikey')); // get api key from store
      $name = $uriPrefix . '.gigya.com/JS/socialize.js?apikey=' . $gigyaApiKey; // set full socialize url
      $jsParams = array( // set config basic params (enabledProviders, lang, sessionExpiration, connectWithoutLoginBehavior)
        'enabledProviders' => (Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf/providers') !== '') ? Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf/providers') : '*',
        'lang' => Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf/laguages'),
        'sessionExpiration' => (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('web/cookie/cookie_lifetime'),
        'connectWithoutLoginBehavior' => Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf/loginBehavior'),
      );
      // add advanced configuration
      $advanced_config = Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf/advancedConfig');
      if($advanced_config !== '') {
        $advanced_config_arr = Mage::helper('Gigya_Social')->getGigGlobalAdvancedConfig($advanced_config);
        if(!$advanced_config_arr) {
          $advanced_config_arr = Mage::helper('Gigya_Social')->_confStringToArry($advanced_config);
        }
        foreach ($advanced_config_arr as $key => $val) {
          $jsParams[$key] = $val;
        }
      }
      ////
      $this->_data['items']['js/gigya'] = array( // set template data parameters for script tag
        'type' => 'external_js',
        'name' => $name,
        'if' => '',
        'cond' => '',
        'params' => Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($jsParams),
      );
      if (Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_global/gigya_global_conf/google_sa')) {
        $ga = $uriPrefix . '.gigya.com/js/gigyaGAIntegration.js';
        $this->_data['items']['js/gigyaGA'] = array(
          'type' => 'external_js',
          'name' => $ga,
          'if' => '',
          'cond' => '',
        );
      }

      $userMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('gigya_login/gigya_user_management/login_modes');
      // check store base url / base secure url addresses
   //   $isSecure = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure();
      $isSecure = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? $_SERVER['HTTPS'] : NULL;
      if ($isSecure) {
        $baseUrl = Mage::getUrl('', array('_secure'=>true));
      } else {
        $baseUrl =  Mage::getBaseUrl();
      }
      // Set JS base url
      $this->_data['items']['js/baseUrl'] = array(
        'type' => 'inline_js',
        'name' => 'baseUrl',
        'if' => '',
        'cond' => '',
        'params' => 'var baseUrl = "' . $baseUrl . '",
          gigyaMageSettings = gigyaMageSettings || {};
          gigyaMageSettings.userMode = "' . $userMode . '";'
      );
        if ($userMode == "raas") { // in raas mode add extra params to js base url
            $this->_data['items']['js/baseUrl']['params'] .=  'gigyaMageSettings.RaaS = ' . Mage::helper('Gigya_Social')->getPluginConfig('gigya_login/gigya_raas_conf') . ';';
        }
    } else {
        parent::_construct();
    }
  }

  protected function _separateOtherHtmlHeadElements(&$lines, $itemIf, $itemType, $itemParams, $itemName, $itemThe) {
    $params = $itemParams ? ' ' . $itemParams : '';
    $href = $itemName;
    switch ($itemType) {
      case 'rss':
        $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<link href="%s"%s rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" />',
          $href, $params
        );
        break;
      case 'link_rel':
        $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<link%s href="%s" />', $params, $href);
        break;

      case 'external_js':
        $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s">%s</script>', $href, $params);
        break;
      case 'inline_js':
        $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<script type"text/javascript">%s</script>', $params);
        break;

    }
  }

  public function getCssJsHtml() {
    // separate items by types
    $lines = array();
    foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $item) {
      if (!is_null($item['cond']) && !$this->getData($item['cond']) || !isset($item['name'])) {
        continue;
      }
      $if = !empty($item['if']) ? $item['if'] : '';
      $params = !empty($item['params']) ? $item['params'] : '';
      switch ($item['type']) {
        case 'js': // js/*.js
        case 'skin_js': // skin/*/*.js
        case 'js_css': // js/*.css
        case 'skin_css': // skin/*/*.css
          $lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
          break;
        default:
          $this->_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements($lines, $if, $item['type'], $params, $item['name'], $item);
          break;
      }
    }

    // prepare HTML
    $shouldMergeJs = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/js/merge_files');
    $shouldMergeCss = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/css/merge_css_files');
    $html = '';
    foreach ($lines as $if => $items) {
      if (empty($items)) {
        continue;
      }
      if (!empty($if)) {
          if (strpos($if, "><!-->") == false) {
        $html .= '<!--[if ' . $if . ']>' . "\n";
          }
      }

      // static and skin css
      $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />' . "\n",
        empty($items['js_css']) ? array() : $items['js_css'],
        empty($items['skin_css']) ? array() : $items['skin_css'],
        $shouldMergeCss ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedCssUrl') : NULL
      );
      // other stuff
      if (!empty($items['other'])) {
        $html .= $this->_prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items['other']) . "\n";
      }

      // static and skin javascripts
      $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
        empty($items['js']) ? array() : $items['js'],
        empty($items['skin_js']) ? array() : $items['skin_js'],
        $shouldMergeJs ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedJsUrl') : NULL
      );


      if (!empty($if)) {
          if (strpos($if, "><!-->") == false) {
        $html .= '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
          }
      }
    }
    return $html;
  }
}
```

Comment: for which purpose ,are you want to use this class?

Comment: I want to convert m1 extension to m2 extension.some m1 extension rewriting above class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent for that class in Magento2.
If you want to add something to the `<head>` tag you can use `reference="head.additional"`.
For more details check the answer to this question: [Magento 2: Adding Arbitrary HTML to the <head> of Every Page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/92904/146)