# Magento 2: add INLINE script tag into header through XML

Tags: magento2, javascript, xml

I'm trying to add an **inline** script tag into the header, by creating a new text block in *default_head_blocks.xml*, but my **setText** method doesn't seem to be applying it correctly.

---

Here's my setup:

*THEME_DIR/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <block type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="my_script">
        <action method="setText">
            <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                <![CDATA[<script>console.log("I'm loaded!");</script>]]>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</head>
</page>
```

---

What is the correct way to insert inline script tags into the header?

Comment: Which is your purpose when you do this?

Comment: The script tag will be pinging a third party server to initialize some fonts, otherwise I'd make a require.js module and load it that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Magento 2 page layout `<head>` element appears not to take/render blocks. Strangely enough, the way to add text to the head element is by referencing `head.additional` in the `<body>` element, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <reference name="head.additional">
            <block type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="my_script">
                <action method="setText">
                    <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                        <![CDATA[<script>console.log("I'm loaded!");</script>]]>
                     </argument>
                </action>
             </block>
        </reference>
    </body>
</page>
```

for Magento 2.1 you have to edit the code like this:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="my_script">
            <action method="setText">
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                    <![CDATA[<script>console.log("I'm loaded!");</script>]]>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

See this excellent answer by Marius here for more: **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92908/5134**

Also, my code above modifies your example. I suggest changing from `<action>` to `<arguments>`, as `<action>` is deprecated. In addition to that, this is likely a good place to use a `<layout>` element as the root - that will allow you to drop the `<page>` and `<body>` tags.

Please let me know if you have any other questions, or if anything doesn't make sure.

Comment: props for give 2.1 example

Comment: Does anyone know how to use in the Layout Update Xml  in static pages? this code doesn't work !