# Adding <referenceBlock name=“head.additional”> Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, head

I had these blocks in the frontend layout:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_sellerprofile" template="profile.phtml" cacheable="false" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
    <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_sellerprofileleft" template="profile_left_sidebar.phtml" cacheable="false" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_sellerprofileright" template="profile_right_sidebar.phtml" cacheable="false" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

then i wanted to add a new block in order to insert it in the section. I added the following command above these blocks

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
  <block class="Dfl\Marketplace\Block\Profile" name="marketplace_social_tags" template="social_tags.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

then in my social_tags.phtml template I just added a simple meta entry.

[image]

Then I run setup:upgrade and setup:static-content:deploy en_US es_ES But the entry wasn't there in the head tag. I followed these links yet i was unable to display the meta entries.

[Adding blocks to the head section in Magento 2](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-blocks-to-head-section/)

[magento-2-adding-arbitrary-html-to-the-head-of-every-page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92904/magento-2-adding-arbitrary-html-to-the-head-of-every-page)

Any help? What it's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue related with the path.
Was View by default i changed to view and the template worked and the meta content appeared.

Answer (score 4):

Create default.xml in `app/code/Dfl/Marketplace/view/frontend/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="marketplace_social_tags" template="Dfl_Marketplace::social_tags.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create `social_tags.phtml` in `app/code/Dfl/Marketplace/view/frontend/templates`

```
<meta property="og:imagen" content="TEST_CONTENT" />
```

Run Magento frontend and check view-source

[image]

Comment: Hello, We have added below code to our extension default.xml file but its not working.

Comment: <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="rtest" template="Test_Module::test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: @Vish it is not `referenceContainer` it is `referenceBlock `

Comment: Adding blocks in head.additional override default_head_blocks.xml and then add your blocks.Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164901/adding-referenceblock-name-head-additional-magento-2-not-working