# Magento2: How to add code inside the head tag?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, script, head

I'm working on a Magento 2 website and I'm trying to add some code to the head tag, I already tried to add going to `Content->Configuration->HTML Head` and pasting the code inside "**Scripts and Style Sheets**" field but the code always goes under the open tag body.

Comment: Ever took a look at the search? First find: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92908/15317

Comment: I want to add the code directly in the admin panel