# Magento 2: How to add "async" attribute to <script> links in document head

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I want to add the `async` attribute to a script tag in the `<head>` block. I've successfully added the script tag to the `default_head_blocks.xml` file in `Magento_Theme` as per the [example in the Devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css), but can't work out how to add an additional attribute to the tag with Magento 2.

I've tried:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" async="async"/>
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to do this using Layout XML as I would have in Magento 1. Instead I used the approach in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92908/55634

In `default.xml` I added a new template to the `head.additional` block:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-head-assets" template="head/custom-head.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**Note** it's important that this block is added within `<body>` - although the template will actually be output in the `<head>`.

Then in the template I can add HTML for `<script>` and `<link>` tags with whatever attributes I want, e.g.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create that JS file in your module and use below code.

```
<script async="async" src="Vendor_ModuleName::js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

if you want to use in Theme

```
<script async="async" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

For defer, You can follow the below code :

```
<script defer="defer" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```