# Magento 2 Error : what is this error?

Tags: magento2, xml

Tried to install a store locator extension.

When go to the front end producing this error.

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
>   Line: 708
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
>   Line: 708
>
> 0 D:\xampp\htdocs\tork\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('
>   
>   1D:\xampp\htdocs\tork\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('

How can i fix this issue?.
**Magento version 2.2.2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most probably you have in one of your layout files a `<block>` tag inside the `<head>` tag.
The `<head>` tag does not support `block` child elements.
See the xsd validation schema for head section: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/head.xsd#L51

If your next question is, "But I need to add a block to my head section. how do I do that?" then you can check this:  [Magento 2: Adding Arbitrary HTML to the <head> of Every Page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/92904/146)

Comment: Oh yeah....or the other way around. Didn't think this could be :)

Comment: Element 'route': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( resources ). any help?