# Element 'body': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i am so tired. please help me.

PHP 7.1
Magento 2.3

```
    1 exception(s)
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'body': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 767


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'body': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 767

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:476]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:457]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:171]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php:74]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:24]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#27 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#29 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Comment: Refer this link for same. you can help.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177261/magento-2-how-to-solve-the-message-character-content-other-than-whitespace

Comment: i tried this solution, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Try this 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219884/magento-2-error-what-is-this-error

Comment: Did you change any layout xml?

Comment: no, i did not changed. i changed en_US to en_GB in admin panel. chain of errors started. a lot of error in solution. but i can not this error.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with an error very similar to this, but unfortunately provided almost no clue of the culprit. Instead of disabling each module one by one, I have decided to output the entire compiled layouts and look by eye.

In the file **vendor\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php**, go to line 460, which should show `if (count($errors)) {`, and within that if block, add the following line above the throw:

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( $dom->saveHTML() ); exit;
```

Now when there's a formatting error in an XML file, it will display all the fetched layouts. When you find the issue, simply search your project for that part of the text, and it should lead you straight to that file. If you're still struggling to locate the issue, you can copy the entire output and parse it through an XML checker.

When you are satisfied that it's been fixed, simply undo the changes made in Dom.php .

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this error:
I removed one by one xml files, till I found in which one is the problem, and I found it in one of the extensions. Hope this is helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This article helps solving it

https://softomars.com/2020/12/22/magento-2-exception-character-content-other-than-whitespace-is-not-allowed-because-the-content-type-is-element-only/